# is it okay to set include_top =true and add more FC in VGG16 pretrained model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning

I've read a lot of tutorial on the internet hwo to implement vgg16 pretrained model in tensorflow, and they always set include_top = false, but when i try in my own project, i got better result when i set it to true and add more FC , in the doc said that include_top = false means that we dont use vgg16 fc, is it okay to use it and add more FC?

here's my code

```
vggmodel = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
for layers in (vggmodel.layers)[:19]:
    print(layers)
    layers.trainable = False
X= vggmodel.layers[-3].output
X=Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')(X)
X=Dense(units = 64, activation = 'relu')(X)
predictions = Dense(3, activation="softmax")(X)
```

Comment: `include_top=True` takes the last layer, but from your model structure, you are not using the last 2 layers.

Comment: is it normal to  set include_top = true ? because every tutorial ive read they set it false, and why i set it true because i get better result

Comment: By setting `include_top=False`, you remove the last layer. We do this to reuse the old weights. 

You are not using the last two layers, so you are essentially also doing Transfer Learning.